# Branching Model for multiple disparate projects. Independent front end and back end projects wo use which branching model to keep in sync?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

To start with, we are trying to find out a git branching model to enable better bug and feature tracking in commits for a team of 15 people and growing. We have searched the various models on web and are favoring to use http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Also we do have different project for front end and back end which interact via json interface. Different repository are maintained on git for providing added security by restricting access to files and folders.

Considering the above scenario, we are trying to work with this git flow model in both sides and integrate both sides following a preplanned schedule.
We would branch from the develop branch and include all the latest code from both the repositories and push back. Which would then be tested and cycle goes again for bug fixing the same.

Though during this testing period the frequency of integration will increase making the develop branch less stable and containing untested newly merged code. And also during this period the long running branches might be blocked from pushing to development.

After we have a stable develop branch we would branch to release branch and then to master for deployment.
Hence when an hot fix issue is detected front end team and back end team will need to fix and integrate it on both repos and then deploy to production after testing. This hot fix again needs to be merged with the develop branch on both sides.

Overall the process seems very complicated and might cause many issues if schedule is not followed or many hot fixes occur to make the code unstable.

So will it help to follow such a process for separate repositories?
What other strategies are available to use for such scenario considering a small team?